# My apartment uses a gas furnace. The gas technician shut off the gas to the furnace stating that "the return air box not sealed"

Tags: furnace, natural-gas

We had a gas service interruption the other day. When the gas technician come by to turn on the service, he noticed that the gas furnace had "holes". He then shut off the gas to the furnace and left a warning notice stating "the return air box not sealed" because the air didn't flow properly. Could anyone help with understanding this issue? My gas furnace return box has a filter inside, is he talking to seal inside or outside?

[image]

Is the section within the red circle the air return box? Not sure if the technician needs the inside or outside to be sealed?

Comment: Is the section within the red circle the air return box? Does the technician need the outside or inside to be sealed?

Comment: Kind of hard to tell from that angle, but where do you insert the air filter?  Is this installed in a closet with space underneath or is it sitting on the floor?

Comment: Can see an inspector turning off the gas and telling you to get it fixed, but seems to a technician job to fix it, if you give permission/ask for it to be done.  It is their job.

Comment: @crip659 I had a similar shutoff during a "courtesy" inspection when we established service after moving into a new place.  Tech was happy to shut off the gas and red tag the service, but he won't touch the equipment.  Similar to a TelCo or PoCo - their responsibility stops at the interface point.  The local Gas co will extend their influence to each appliance connection, but won't go further than that.

Comment: If "apartment in the rental sense" you call your landlord to deal with it. If "apartment but you own it" Then you get to have someone service the thing. Not clear what is meant - possibly a rusted-through heat exchanger...